# ffmpeg drawtext with multiple colors

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to work on some videos. I'm resizing each video down to a smaller size, padding it, and overlaying a static image overlaying the padding. Right now the static image has one textbox that says some information about the video. That was simple enough. I want to also add more information to the static image, though. I want to add information about the order of videos, with the current video being a different color. For example, I want text that looks like the following:
Video1→Video2→Video→VIDEO4→Video5→Video6

Where VIDEO4 is a different color, so we can easily see where we are in the order. It doesn't seem to be that easily done with ffmpeg:

- I don't believe I could do multiple colors using one "drawtext" filter
- If I have multiple textboxes (one for previous videos in the list, one for the current video in the list, and one for the videos-to-come), they don't line up very well horizontally, as the actual names of the video have varying lengths of text. It's a bit of a nightmare.
- I can't use ASS scripts/subtitles because it's being put on static image, not a video

Is there any other solution to this other than just attempting to guess at the X value of these drawtext filters? Could I actually use some sort of subtitle script on an image? Am I able to reference other textboxes? If so, I could at least calculate the width of the textbox and position the next one accordingly. Everything I've seen so far has had some sort of timestamp beginning and end, and I just want it there for the whole video.

I'm using python and the ffmpeg-python library to interface with ffmpeg. This allows me to use a configuration file so I can dynamically add/remove videos to be created.

Just for more information, here's a snippit of how I'm making the videos:

```py
        overlay_input = ffmpeg.input(overlay_image)\
                              .drawtext(text="blahblahblah",
                                        ... text options...)
        video_input = ffmpeg.input(video, re=None)\
                      .video\
                      .filter("scale",
                              ...scaling options...)\
                      .filter("pad",
                              ...padding options...)\
                      .overlay(overlay_input)
```

Any information would be very appreciated!

Comment: *I can't use ASS scripts/subtitles because it's being put on static image, not a video* --> why not? You aren't animating the subtitle.

Comment: I'm super unfamiliar with ASS scripts, so when I saw timestamps for everything I assumed I couldn't use it on static images. I briefly used Aegisub and it only allowed me to open video files. I can try doing it for the image.

Comment: @Gyan I never thanked you for this solution. I was able to use the one script and it worked great. I really appreciate it :)